# Time Series figures finder

Tags: machine-learning, time-series

I have been working on a continuous Time Series with the objective of creating an algorithm that finds some specific kind of figures defined by the graph of the curve.
I partially solved the problem looking for mathematical conditions that the points should satisfy in order to consider the figure that I'm looking for. However I would like to know if this can be done with ML tools.

Some of the figures that I automated are:

1. Mountain shaped figure bounded by two similar stabilities
   [image]
2. A ladder looking figure bounded by an initial stability and a final stability
   [image]

I know that this is very vague, but that is the idea of what I'm looking for.
I tried using Dynamic time warping in order to find similar shaped figures but it does not worked so well in order to find these figures.

Is there anything useful that I can study in order to attack this problem?

Comment: You could of course train a deep neural network with a custom loss function to do this, but you would need a lot of labeled training data.

Answer (score 1):

Image recognition and shape detection have great results using Convolutional Neural Networks and could be applied to time series.

The main advantage of CNN is detecting curve shapes in any position, but it requires many samples to be trained correctly.

Therefore, you can apply 2D CNN.

Tensorflow has a 2D CNN function:

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv2D

And Pytorch too:

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv2d.html

Here is a code that could be applied to your case:

https://towardsdatascience.com/a-simple-2d-cnn-for-mnist-digit-recognition-a998dbc1e79a

If you need to find different shapes in a single picture, you can apply bounding boxes that detect main shapes automatically.

https://pyimagesearch.com/2020/10/05/object-detection-bounding-box-regression-with-keras-tensorflow-and-deep-learning/

Comment: Does it answer your question? If not, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try rolling standard deviation or max min difference in a couple of reasonable window sizes and combine it with plain rolling mean

UPD Another plain baseline manual approach

```
> enframe(c(
+     rnorm(10, sd=0.1), 
+     rnorm(10, sd=0.1) + 1,
+     rnorm(10, sd=0.1))) %>% 
+     rename(i = name) %>% 
+     mutate(abs_dif=abs(value - lag(value))) %>% 
+     arrange(desc(abs_dif)) %>% 
+     mutate(rel_dif_dif=1 - round(lead(abs_dif) / abs_dif, 2))
# A tibble: 30 x 4
       i   value abs_dif rel_dif_dif
   <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>       <dbl>
 1    21  0.0292   1.10       0.2   
 2    11  0.963    0.884      0.66  
 3    10  0.0789   0.305      0.0300
 4    19  1.13     0.295      0.15  
 5    30  0.281    0.250      0.0400
 6     8 -0.103    0.239      0.24  
 7     4 -0.139    0.182      0.0600
 8     3  0.0433   0.170      0.0500
 9    23 -0.0222   0.161      0.0400
10    14  0.843    0.155      0.0300
```

Filtering by max `rel_dif_dif` left indicies of the beginnigns of the steps

Comment: Those are the kind of ideas that I'm currently using to find the figures.